# How to refresh the owlCarrousel elements, omitting the ones that are display: none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am using owlCarousel, and I have added a search engine, but I need to update the dots and the nav elements of the same.

Before filtering:
[image]

After filtering, I want that the dots are also updated and when clicking on the right nav or left nav, do not take into account the times that have a display: none.

[image]

```js
var rtl = !1;
var _tg_postsslider = $("#tg-dbcategoriesslider");
_tg_postsslider.owlCarousel({
    items: 2,
    nav: true,
    rtl: rtl,
    loop: !1,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: !1,
    navClass: ["tg-prev", "tg-next"],
    navContainerClass: "tg-slidernav",
    navText: ['<span class="icon-chevron-left"></span>', '<span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>'],
    responsive: {0: {items: 2}, 640: {items: 3}, 768: {items: 4}},
    info: function(info, element){
     console.log(info);
    }
});
$('.live-search-list .tg-category').each(function(){
 $(this).attr('data-cat-name', $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim());
});

$(document).on('keyup','.live-search-box', function(){
 var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 $('.live-search-list .tg-category').each(function(){
     if ($(this).filter('[data-cat-name *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
         $(this).parent().parent().show();
     } else {
         $(this).parent().parent().hide();
     }
 });

 _tg_postsslider.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, without the code the images might be useless.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have already added the code, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @JoséCabrera thank you for including your code. What would be great is if it was [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.